# Facebook scraper not seeing Opengrapth Meta Tags on shop products using PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I really hope someone on this site can help me with this problem, I have been looking for days now but just can't find a solution.

I have an e-commerce website containing 100's of products and I am trying to put a Facebook share button on each product. I display each individual item through single.php and access this file with single.php?pid=52 for example which comes from a product page.

At the beginning of 'single.php' I have as follows:

```
$file1 = $pid . ".php"; // a reference to a file containing relevant Open 
Graph metadata which is stored on the server

$metadata = glob('images/products/metadata/'. $file1); // Gets the filename from the server a puts it in to an array $metadata[0];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>wish Interiors</title>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://wishinteriors.com/single.php">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="keywords" content="" >
<meta name="description" content="At Wish Interiors, all our reproduction furniture are handmade using the finest craftsmen and quality workmanship so you are sure to get a luxury handmade piece of furniture every time.">
<!--FACEBOOK-->
<?php
require $metadata[0];

require "includes/header-single.php"; // this contains the rest of the header data
```

The metadata file contains as follows:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Bespoke furniture makers" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Wish Interiors" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://wishinteriors.com/single.php" />
<meta property="og:description" content="At Wish Interiors, all our 
reproduction furniture are handmade using the finest craftsmen and quality 
workmanship so you are sure to get a luxury handmade piece of furniture every 
time." />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en-US" />
<meta property="og:image" 
content="https://wishinteriors.com/images/products/Fillipo%203seater.jpg" />
```

The %20 in the image file name is there because it has spaces in the name, I did a test and the scraper seemed to accept this method.

The problem is that facebook scraper just refuses to see the Open Graph data, even though I can see it fine if a do a view source for the browse. What I would like to know, is there an alternative way of doing this or even is it possible at all to have dynamic data sent to the scraper, or do I have to physically have a page for each product containing the header data and product information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew, but could you elaborate on your answer please, as I don't quite understand what you mean when you say your canonical is not unique, Sorry but I am new to Facebook sharing, thanks.

Comment: Sorry I mean the og:url needs to be unique for each product. Use the Facebook debugger to test your product links.  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/  Your canonical URL should be https://wishinteriors.com

Comment: Thanks for replying and explaining I will see if that does the trick

Comment: Sorry but with reference to your answer Andrew, does that mean I will need a different page for each product, as at the moment I am pulling the data for each product from a MySQL database and dynamically showing it through the one page e.g single.php, thanks for your patience

Comment: That's a very bad way of doing it especially for SEO rankings.  You should use something like the product category and product name in the url for each product to make it unique.

Comment: Ok thanks, it looks like I have a lot of work ahead of me lol, thank you very much for your advice